# Relationship Between Current and Power in a Refrigerator

Tags: power, current

I have a refrigerator with the following characteristics:

Condensing Unit Size 1/2 H.P.
Voltage (International) 115/60/1
Total Amps (International) 7.7
Defrost Amps (International) 4.4

What generates doubt for me is that: The power is 1/2 HP, which is equal to 372 W, but if I calculate it:

120 V x 7.7 A = 924 W

So, why does the specification sheet say 1/2 HP?

Comment: Rated current for many types of products is meant for fuse sizing. I’m no expert on refrigerators, but your average power supply is usually rated for max running peak current at lowest voltage, worst power factor, plus margin, plus VAT. I’ll try to find a previous answer for you and link to it.

Comment: Please photograph the boilerplate of the condenser and post a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Defrost Amps: 4.4" means that up to 4.4A are used by the defrost heater, which is a separate thing from the compressor.

7.7A - 4.4A = 3.3A.

3.3A * 115V = 379W, which is quite a nice match for 1/2 HP.

Comment: Thanks but what would be the FLA?

Comment: @JuliánOviedo of the refrigerator? 7.7. Of the compressor? 3.3.